# Where i will get English setup for gvSIG?

Tags: gvsig

I am trying to install gvSIG. It is asking me which setup language, i selected English. But when installation is complete it is giving me interface with Russian language. Can any one help me to install or download the English version setup?

Comment: Remember that it's a good practice select an answer as correct

Answer (score 8):

What regional settings do you have?

Take a look at this nice youtube video: [How to change gvSIG language](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoMrGlE0LOk)

Comment: ey it's great when someone answers exactly what you were going to write and pointing to your video :-)

Comment: Very usefull video BTW, great job Jorge!

Answer (score 3):

If you have trouble accessing the preferences (I can imagine that if your interface is in Russian) you can just edit your $HOME/gvSIG/andami-config.xml where you have to change the value of the attribute "locale-language" to "en" for example. See screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a command line option that you can use to start gvSIG in the language that you want:

```
-language=ISO_CODE_FOR_THE_LANGUAGE
```

In linux to launch gvSIG in English you can use

```
./gvSIG.sh -language=en
```